# What is wrong with my implementation of a method to add row to a primefaces datatable?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using JavaServer Faces 2.0, and Primefaces 3.5 and am running this on a Glassfish 3.1.2. I have a data table on a page that is used to allow a user to create a trivia question, set its properties, and add possible answers to it, then store it as an entity object in a table. So I created a data table using the Primefaces implementation of the data table

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="answersTable" var="answer" style="width: 250px"
    value="#{createQuestionBean.datamodel}"   
    selection="#{createQuestionBean.selectedAnswer}"
    editMode="cell" editable="true"
    selectionMode="single">

    <p:column style="width:75%"> 
        <p:cellEditor >  
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText 
                    value="#{answer.answer.testAnswer}" />
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText 
                    id="modelInput"  
                    style="width: 97%;height: 97%"
                    value="#{answer.answer.testAnswer}"/>
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>  
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:25%">  
        #{answer.correct ? "Correct" : "Wrong" }  
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

I added a button after the table to allow the user to add an answer (So they could have more than 2 possible answers)

```
<p:commandButton 
    update="answersTable"
    value="Add +" partialSubmit="true"
    actionListener="#{createQuestionBean.addQuestion}"/>
```

This is the method that is called by the button

```
public void addQuestion() {
    answers.add(new QuestionAnswers());
    answers.get(answers.size() - 1).setCorrect(false);
    setIDs();
    //set the data models
    datamodel = new QuestionAnswersDataModel(answers);
}
```

When I run the init method I call the addQuestion() method twice and when the page loads I see both answers, which act exactly like they should. However, when I click on the button, I got nothing but this Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Unable to create new Collection instance for type java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.createCollection(MenuRenderer.java:907)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:367)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:129)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:315)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectmanycheckbox.SelectManyCheckboxRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectManyCheckboxRenderer.java:37)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I cannot find where my issue is. I know I instantiate the list in the init method, and even if I hadn't it wouldn't have loaded the page. The exception only happens when the button is pressed, and only the first time.

Comment: What does `datamodel = new QuestionAnswersDataModel(answers);` do?

Comment: To allow for the selection of a single, or multiple records, in order to do processing on one of them. I'm using the example from the primefaces site: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `datamodel.setWrappedData(answers);` Instead

As to *why* it happened; while I can't give you the specifics (and I can't seem to get the source of the implementation of `DataModel`) it seems that `DataModel`, at some point attempts to create an instance of `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`. The `ArraysList` we're talking about here is not the one from `java.util` but an [inner class of the `Arrays` class](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html).

Also, you might be interested in knowing that you don't actually *need* the `DataModel` class. You can use the `ArrayList` as-is. That way, you won't need to re-wrap a brand new array every time you modify the datamodel. Simply add to the `java.util.ArrayList` and reRender your datatable

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
`datamodel = new QuestionAnswersDataModel(answers);`

to

`datamodel = new QuestionAnswersDataModel(new ArrayList<QuestionAnswers>(answers));`

That should solve the issue.

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: It doesn't event run the addQuestion() method apparently, I put a breakpoint on the first line and it never ran.